# GWT: Dynamically convert HorizontalPanel to VerticalPAnel

Tags: java, gwt

How can I programatically convert HorizontalPanel to VerticalPanel? Is it possible?

**From:**

```
<g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="panel">

</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

**To:**

```
<g:VerticalPanel ui:field="panel">

</g:VerticalPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

Would the snippet below work? (dont have a GWT environment setup to test it):

```
public SomeClass extends Composite {

@UiField
CellPanel panel;

    public SomeClass() {    
        panel = new VerticalPanel;
    }
}
```

OR even better why dont you use in your ui.xml

```
<g:CellPanel ui:field="panel">

</g:CellPanel >
```

and do it anything you want in java code (since HorizontalPanel and VerticalPanel are subclasses of CellPanel)?

Comment: your code won't work. First composite is not initialized, so in the constructor you should have initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)) and after that - DOM will be populated, so to delay the CellPanel creation you'll need to change your annotation a bit '@UiField(provided = true)' and put panel creation before initWidget

Comment: My code is not complete and of course won't run as is. I think this is pretty obvious. More or less I wanted to provide some hint to the original poster.

Answer (score -1):

No It's not possible in a way you imagine it.
Once widgets populated into DOM tree you can't dynamically re-cast them
A few workarounds to suggest

**Worst approach possible**

1. Copy the list of vertical panel child widgets
2. Remove vertical panel from DOM tree
3. Insert horizontal panel instead
4. Add all child nodes of vertical panel to horizontal panel

**A better way**

If you can give up on IE6, IE7 support, what you can actually do is use `<g:FlowPanel>` with `display: flex;`
Here's an example for you:

```
<ui:style>
.flexPanel{
  display: flex;
}
.vertical{
  flex-direction: column;
}
</ui:style>
<!-- then in your uibinder-->
<g:FlowPanel ui:field="panel" addStyleName="{style.flexPanel}"> 
<!-- will act as horizontal panel by default-->
</g:FlowPanel>
```

Then any time you want to change orientation just do something like:

```
panel.addStyleName(style.vertical());
//or if you want it back to horizontal
panel.removeStyleName(style.vertical());
```

For the sake of simplicity I didn't put css prefixes to flex-properties, if you're targeting not only modern browsers, prefix both classes like here:

```
.flexPanel{
 display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.vertical{
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And yeah, take CSS a good look. Don't use those old table layouts, It's 2016 now. Check this simple article, it helped our team to transition fast enough:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/